# Minecraft Forge 1.7.10 - Removing recipes from ID

Tags: java, config, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make a small utility mod for Minecraft 1.7.10 in which you place a list of IDs in a config file and the mod removes their recipes from the game. I've got the config file working but I don't seem to be able to remove the recipes.

My method for removing the recipes is one I have seen in a couple of forum threads elsewhere and slightly modified to work with my config file (or not work in my case).

Here is the method:

```
private void removeRecipes(String toDelete)
{

    ArrayList<?> recipes = (ArrayList<?>) CraftingManager.getInstance().getRecipeList();

    ItemStack recipeResult = null;

    ItemStack resultItem = new ItemStack((Item)Item.itemRegistry.getObject(toDelete));
    resultItem.stackSize = 1;
    resultItem.setItemDamage(0);

    for (int scan = 0; scan < recipes.size(); scan++)
    {
         IRecipe tmpRecipe = (IRecipe) recipes.get(scan);
         if (tmpRecipe instanceof ShapedRecipes)
       {
             ShapedRecipes recipe = (ShapedRecipes)tmpRecipe;
             recipeResult = recipe.getRecipeOutput();

             recipeResult.stackSize = 1;
             recipeResult.setItemDamage(0);
       }
         if (tmpRecipe instanceof ShapelessRecipes)
         {
             ShapelessRecipes recipe = (ShapelessRecipes)tmpRecipe;
             recipeResult = recipe.getRecipeOutput();

             recipeResult.stackSize = 1;
             recipeResult.setItemDamage(0);
         }
         if (ItemStack.areItemStacksEqual(resultItem, recipeResult))
         {
             System.out.println("[RecipeRemover] Removed Recipe: " + recipes.get(scan) + " -> " + recipeResult);
             recipes.remove(scan);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not have the source of mc anymore, but I assume the `CraftingManager.getInstance().getRecipeList()` returns a clone of the arraylist, not the actual list. Im guessing you should use reflection to achieve what you are doing :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something was obviously a bit out with my code, but this is a much more efficient approach which works (and should work universally):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void removeRecipes(String toDelete)
{    
    ItemStack resultItem = new ItemStack((Item)Item.itemRegistry.getObject(toDelete));
    resultItem.stackSize = 1;
    resultItem.setItemDamage(0);

    List<IRecipe> recipes = CraftingManager.getInstance().getRecipeList();

    for (int i = 0; i < recipes.size(); i++)
    {
        IRecipe tmpRecipe = recipes.get(i);

        ItemStack recipeResult = tmpRecipe.getRecipeOutput();
        if(recipeResult != null) 
        {
            recipeResult.stackSize = 1;
            recipeResult.setItemDamage(0);
        }

        if (ItemStack.areItemStacksEqual(resultItem, recipeResult))
        {
            recipes.remove(i--);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am taking essentially the same approach here and it works well enough.